# I get the error FirebaseException ([firebase_storage/object-not-found] No object exists at the desired reference.)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-storage

```
        late File uploadFile;
  FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  String? downloadUrl;

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getUrl());
    super.initState();
  }

  void getUrl() async {
    String con = await FirebaseStorage.instance // It shows the error for this line.

        .ref()
        .child("profilePics")
        .child(auth.currentUser!.uid)
        .child("profilePic.png")
        .getDownloadURL();

    setState(() {
      downloadUrl = con;
    });
  }

  void gallery() async {
    var getDoc = await ImagePicker().pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      uploadFile = File(getDoc!.path);
    });

    final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance
        .ref()
        .child("profilePics")
        .child(auth.currentUser!.uid)
        .child("profilePic.png");

    UploadTask uploadTask = ref.putFile(uploadFile);
    String url = await (await uploadTask).ref.getDownloadURL();
    
    setState(() {
      downloadUrl = url;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut(),
              child: Text('Çıkış'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                gallery();
              },
              child: Text('Upload'),
            ),
            downloadUrl != null ? Image.network(downloadUrl!) : CircleAvatar()
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Everything was working properly when I first wrote the code. By signing in, I have the user select a profile photo from the gallery. Then I clicked on a picture and that picture was both uploaded to Storage and came to the area where the profile picture should be in the application. But the problem in the title appeared when I logged in with another account. It gives this error before reaching the profile picture selection screen and stops the application.

Comment: Remove the `await` in front of the `FirebaseStorage.instance` and it should work.

Comment: it gives this error, A value of type 'Future<String>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'. Try changing the type of the variable, or casting the right-hand type to 'String'.

Comment: Sorry my fault, I thought the line was just `String con = FirebaseStorage.instance` and I was wondering why the return type would be a string, but just saw now the line continues below

Comment: I understand So, do you know the solution? I've been stuck here for a few hours.

Comment: Is it possible the image doesn't exist yet when you try to `getDownloadURL()`? Are you sure you have it uploaded before?